# How to read multiple files into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, r

I want to make array in 3 dimension.

Here is what I tried:

```
z<-c(160,720,420)
first_data_set <-array(dim = length(file_1), dimnames = z)
```

Data that I am reading is in one level. (only x and y)
There are other data in the same format, and I need to put them in the same array with the first data. So once I finish reading all data, all of them are in the same array but there is no overwriting.

So I think array has to be 3 dimensions; otherwise I cannot keep all data that I read in loop.

Comment: If your data isn't related in the 3rd dimension, i would look at a list instead.  Each set of x,y data would be its own list, then you can do whatever processing you want to each list using something like `lapply`.  Faulting that, we'll need much more information to help you...

Comment: what does `file_1` look like? can you paste or link to the output of `dput(file_1)`?

Comment: At the moment the question is overly vague (and possible confused). Will remove my vote to close (and my comment) when you post data example that allows a specific answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say that you have two matrices of size 3x4:

```
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(12), nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
m2 <- matrix(rnorm(12), nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
```

If you want to place them in an array, first make an array of NA's:

```
A <- array(as.numeric(NA), dim = c(3,4,2))
```

Then populate the layers with data:

```
A[,,1] <- m1
A[,,2] <- m2
```

As suggested by @Justin, you could also just put the matrices together in a list:

```
A2 <- list()
A2[['m1']] <- m1
A2[['m2']] <- m2
```

---

To read matrices from files: using a list makes it easier to get these matrices from files in a directory, without having to specify the dimensions in advance. Assume you want all files with extension `csv`:

```
myfiles <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){
   A2[[myfiles[i]]] <- read.table(myfiles[i], sep = ',')
}
```

Comment: mode(A) here begins as logical because of NA's default, and is then coerced to numeric when you assign new values - to ensure that is controlled explicitly consider starting with A <- array(as.numeric(NA), dim = c(3,4,2)) instead

Comment: @DavidLeBauer Thanks a lot :)